# React Project shows empty array but contains value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So currently I'm pulling items from the backend using a service using axios.get() now on my actual file that pulls the service. I use useEffect() to call the service there it calls it, but sometimes I get an empty array [] but when I click on it, it actually contains an object with items do you happen to know why and what I could do to fix it so I can map through the items.
[image]

Comment: Let's not look at any console log for a minute. Is everything working perfectly at UI? Is it rendering properly, probably, using `.map`?

Comment: Maybe post the  ```useEffect``` code pulling this data?